# How to correct sentinel data with sen2cor in R using a json with parameters?

Tags: r, sentinel-2, sen2cor

Reading the sen2r documentation I saw the next example:

```
library(sen2r)
library(sf)

# Download an L1C SAFE product
example_s2_list <- s2_list(
  spatial_extent = st_sfc(st_point(c(12.0, 44.8)), crs=st_crs(4326)),
  tile = "32TQQ",
  time_interval = as.Date(c("2017-05-01","2017-07-30"))
)
s2_download(example_s2_list, outdir = tempdir())

# Correct it applying a topographic correction
sen2cor(
  names(example_s2_list)[1],
  l1c_dir = tempdir(),
  outdir = tempdir(),
  use_dem = TRUE
)
```

In the example the code first checks the products available, then it downloads them and finally with sen2cor it applies some corrections.
My question is if there is a way to put the parameters to correct that from a json previously exported from the GUI with the desired parameters

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way and it is documented here: https://sen2r.ranghetti.info/articles/sen2r_cmd.html

I haven't used this myself, so I can't be of much more help I'm afraid.